# How do I write a countifs function across multiple sheets that pulls from filtered data?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I am attempting to write a countifs function that populates data for my successful projects column. The data will be pulled from a separate page titled kickstarterscrape_06-02-201 with a filtered column.

[Successful Projects Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5yen.png)

The filtered column of the other sheet is titled status within column G, I would only like to pull data for successful projects.

[Filtered Data and Column I will be pulling data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKLjZ.png)

The current function that I have is..

=COUNTIFS('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!G:G="successful",Summary!B6)

However it returns an error. How do I write this correctly?

Comment: You should include the error being returned.

Comment: The error that was originally returned was "Not enough arguments were entered into this function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=COUNTIFS('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!G:G,"successful",Summary!B6,"criteria2")
```

try this, you shouldnt have to put an = just a comma separating the criteria and the range. however you have a criteria range1 and a criteria1 then a criteria range2 but you dont have a second criteria

if you were trying to place the count number in cell B6 on the sheet named summary, place this in that cell:

```
=COUNTIFS('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!G:G,"Art")
```

so if column G in sheet kickstarterscrape_06-02-201 has weather or not it was a success or not and say column B in the same sheet had the category,

```
=COUNTIFS('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!G:G,"successful",kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!D:D,"Art")
```

would show (in the cell that the formula is placed) the number of rows that contain art in column D and successful in column G

Comment: My goal is to place the count number in cell B6 on the sheet named summary, as well as for C6, D6, and so on based on the category of Art, Publishing, Music, Ect. The function...

=COUNTIFS('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!G:G,"successful")

Would only provide the total number of "successful" projects without taking into account the various categories. I will keep working on it and see what I figure out.

Comment: oooh ok, then use that first formula with criteria2 replaced with the category it is checking for and Summary!B6 replaced with the range that the category is located in.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

=COUNTIFS('kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!G:G,"successful",'kickstarterscrape_06-02-201'!D:D,B5)

Comment: @JakeGirouard mark answer as correct if this is what you were looking for